# Changing every route from /product to /eshop in Rails Route 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

in my routes.rb i have foll entries:-

```
  resources :products do  
    get 'get_products', :on => :collection
    get 'show_product_details',:on=>:member
    get 'buy_this',:on=>:collection
    get 'search_product',:on=>:collection 
  end
```

i want to change every /products to /eshop in the url.
i am not sure but can i use `:path=>:eshop`.Will it will be also applicable to the sub routes as well such as `eshop/get_products,eshop/buy_this`...etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your routes and run rake routes in the terminal to check the paths.

```
resources :products, :path => 'eshop', :as => 'eshop' do  
  get 'get_products', :on => :collection
  get 'show_product_details',:on=>:member
  get 'buy_this',:on=>:collection
  get 'search_product',:on=>:collection 
end
```

will produce these

```
  get_products_eshop_index GET        /eshop/get_products(.:format)                              products#get_products
show_product_details_eshop GET        /eshop/:id/show_product_details(.:format)                  products#show_product_details
      buy_this_eshop_index GET        /eshop/buy_this(.:format)                                  products#buy_this
search_product_eshop_index GET        /eshop/search_product(.:format)                            products#search_product
               eshop_index GET        /eshop(.:format)                                           products#index
                           POST       /eshop(.:format)                                           products#create
                 new_eshop GET        /eshop/new(.:format)                                       products#new
                edit_eshop GET        /eshop/:id/edit(.:format)                                  products#edit
                     eshop GET        /eshop/:id(.:format)                                       products#show
                           PUT        /eshop/:id(.:format)                                       products#update
                           DELETE     /eshop/:id(.:format)                                       products#destroy
```

Comment: adding the `as` option is not a good piece of advice: what's the point of maintaining all routes helpers within the app?

Comment: thanks @santosh..but there are already many url helpers that are used..i dont want to replae them,for example `buy_this_products_path` and i have to change it to newly generated url helper to work.dat i dont want.